# “Half an hour” and “half hour” adverbs

Tags: adverbs, compounds, compound-adjectives, compound-words

If the rate per hour is the hourly rate, what do you call the rate for half an hour? What is the rate for 2 hours known as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is called the rate for half an hour ? and the rate for 2 hours

the half-hourly rate

the two-hourly rate